# Firebase User Security Simulation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-console

I'm really scratching my head here, and I've been reading as much as I can on many other cases. I'm new to Firebase, but got some understanding of it. I was wanting to restrict certain records of the database to certain users. So here's my JSON:

```
  "accounts" : {
    "13asdf313" : {
      "dog" : "bacon",
      "email" : "luis@fakeemail.com",
      "first" : "luis",
      "last" : "xxxx"
    },
    "HlELrrGDbiMKgxxxx" : {
      "name" : "Luis"
    },
    "anthony" : {
      "email" : "anthony@fakeemail.com",
      "last" : "xxxx",
      "name" : "anthony"
    },
    "jpSq6UzX0mcAvExxxx" : {
      "name" : "anthony"
    }
  }
```

Here are the rules set up based on what I've been reading:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "accounts":{

      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },

  }


}
```

In the simulator, I used the bottom condition (I even put /accounts in the location field). I used the UID: HlELrrGDbiMKgxxxx, copied straight from Firebase account list.

[image]

This is always coming up as failed

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert `accounts/HlELrrGDbiMKgxxxx` into the *Location* field.

Otherwise you are trying to access the **whole** database (standard location is *root*, which covers the whole database). Your rule is just set for the child `accounts/$uid` and to access it the user id from authentication and the child location in the database must match.

Comment: oooooh, so if I'm querying via URL, I need to add the accounts/<uid> to get all the records that has the <uid> hash?

Comment: Yes, but that should make sense. I mean if you want to access a users account data and the user is logged in, you are provided with the necessary information. In JS the query would look like. `root.child(`accounts/${auth.uid}`).once('value')` and this should return the complete user entry.